# I have a problem with Jdbc.getConnection from google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

At the moment I use mysql for connection to my google app script, however some days ago, I have problem with the function Jdbc.getConnection of GAS, I here share my error. I need to help guys. thanks.

[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMO5Y.png)

Comment: Does your manifest contain this scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and reported in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224071900). You may star the issue to get updates when Google resolves it at their end.

Comment: Google has confirmed that they are working on fixing this bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413841#comment161